# M1 Mac: Debugging intermittent CFe memory card recognition by MacOS

Tags: mac, hard-drive, apple-silicon

I have a M1 Mac and trying to read some memory cards (CF Express B) using a INDMEM card reader. It is a simple card reader that accepts only CFe and does not require a power supply. I can see the card reader appears under `About the MAC -> system report -> USB`. However, only very occasionally do the memory cards that I try to read (there are two of them) get recognized (in the sense that they appear on the desktop), and I don't understand why they are only recognized sometimes.

How can I debug this problem?